# connect to Access database in asp.net and Join statement

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ms-access

Let say there is an  Asp.ne5 3.5 web application with an Access database. The database has two tables like this:

[image]

In some pages I can get the username with `"page.users.identity.name". In this Application, each user can create so many pages. My question is how to write a statement to get pages created with specific username (the Group_ID in joined).

NOTE: This is what i tried and i got "error reading database".

```
SELECT Pages.* FROM 
Pages INNER JOIN Users ON Pages.Group_ID = Users.Group_ID
WHERE Users.Username = page.users.identity.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Missed the Single quote "' " in the statement for page.users.identity.name. now this should be like this:

dim lasts as string= "'"

```
"SELECT Pages.* FROM 
Pages INNER JOIN Users ON Pages.Group_ID = Users.Group_ID
WHERE Users.Username ='" &  page.users.identity.name & lasts
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a parametrized query:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // get the username of the currently connected user
    string username = User.Identity.Name;

    string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(cs))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sql = 
            @"SELECT Pages.* FROM Pages 
              INNER JOIN Users 
              ON Pages.Group_ID = Users.Group_ID
              WHERE Users.Username = ?";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ... 
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query,

```
SELECT Pages.* FROM 
Pages,Users where Pages.Group_ID = Users.Group_ID
and Users.Username = page.users.identity.name
```